# UITextField in UIAlertView: clear button is not centered vertically in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I use the following code to show a UIAlertView with a text field:

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Rename", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

UITextField* textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

[alertView show];
```

The result looks like this on iOS 5.1:

[image]

and on iOS 6.1:

[image]

As you can see, the clear button is a bit higher than it should be on iOS 6.1. Any idea how to properly center the button? Adding       `textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;` does not help either.

(Apparently, this is a bug in iOS 6.1 but maybe someone knows a workaround. Besides, the height of the text field in alert views also seem to differ in different OS versions but that is another issue.)

Comment: Also, look at the 5.1 version. There, it's the *text* that is not centered vertically.

Comment: This may hurt your eyeballs but ultimately this is an Apple (iOS) issue. You should file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com so Apple can be made aware of this (don't forget to include these screenshots).

Comment: This is fixed in iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug from Apple, but you can always add your own clear button in the textField, doing something like this :

First create a UITextField property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
```

And then assign it to the alertView's textField

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Rename", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

self.textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
self.textField.delegate = self;

//Create a custom clear button
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 19)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clearText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

[self.textField setRightView:button];
self.textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

And then in the clearText method,

```
- (void)clearText {
    [self.textField setText:@""];
}
```

I tried this out and it works

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by overriding `UITextField`'s [clearButtonRectForBounds:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/clearButtonRectForBounds%3a).